# My code counts the wrong number of words when the JTextArea is empty

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextarea

I want to count the number of words in a certain JTextArea when I click on a button, but when I run my code when the text area is empty I got the number of words is 1. I don't know what the wrong with my code. Here is my code.

```
private void convertButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
    String text = inputField.getText();
    int wordCount = text.split("\\s").length;
    numberOfWords.setText(String.valueOf(wordCount));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know anything about regex but it appears this is the default behaviour of the split method.

It appears to always return an array with the original value, even if that value happens to be the empty string.

I tried something simple like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    int wordCount = "".split("a").length;
    System.out.println( wordCount );
}
```

and it always displays "1" no matter what character I attempt to split on.

The solution could be something like:

```
    String text = inputField.getText();
    int wordCount = text.isEmpty() ? 0 : text.split("\\s").length;
    numberOfWords.setText(String.valueOf(wordCount));
```